# Given $A = (2,1,3)$ and $B=(4,-1,1)$ and the plane $\alpha \{ \ 2x-y+2z=3$ find line $r$ contained in $\alpha$ equidistant to $A$ and $B$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I am given the following problem:

> Given $A = (2,1,3)$ and $B=(4,-1,1)$ and the plane $\alpha \{ \ 2x-y+2z=3$ find the parametric equations of the line $r$ contained in $\alpha$ such that, for every point in $r$, the distance between $r$ and $A$ is the same as the distance between $r$ and $B$

I am struggling to find the equations that will solve this. I know that the distance between a line and a point is

$$
\delta = \frac{\vert \vec{AP} \wedge \vec{u} \vert}{\Vert \vec{u} \Vert}
$$

if $P$ is a point contained on the line and $\vec{u}$ is the vector that gives the direction of $r$. Also, the normal vector of the plane is

$$
\vec{n} = (2,-1,2)\\
$$

If I say that $\vec{u} = (a,b,c)$ I will have a LOT of variables and a few equations to solve (it won't get me nowhere.

but I honestly cannot go further than this. What piece of information am I missing?

Comment: Let M be the midpoint of A and B take the plane through M and perpendicular to AB. This plane is the set of points equidistant from A and B. Now intersect this plane with your first plane.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

It is the intersection of the plane $\alpha$ and perpendicular bisector plane of segment $[AB]$. The latter is the plane through the midpoint $I$ of $[AB]$, normal to vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$.

For this perpendicular bisector, you should find the cartesian equation $x-y-z=1$.

From there you can easily find a parametric representation of the intersection line.